# Can't open Android Studio Android Device Monitor - error in log file

Tags: android, android-studio, android-device-monitor

In Android Studio when I try to run Android Device Monitor, I encounter the following message in the below log file.

```
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_67
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -data @noDefault

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-01-25 16:25:44.797
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609/@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-01-25 16:25:44.803
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.apache.jasper.glassfish_2.2.2.v201205150955.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-01-25 16:25:44.804
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.apache.lucene.core_2.9.1.v201101211721.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-01-25 16:25:44.861
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.help.base_3.6.101.v201302041200.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-01-25 16:25:44.862
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.help.ui_3.5.201.v20130108-092756.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-01-25 16:25:44.863
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.help.webapp_3.6.101.v20130116-182509.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-01-25 16:25:44.865
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.jetty.server_8.1.3.v20120522.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-01-25 16:25:44.871
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.platform.doc.user_4.2.2.v20130121-200410.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-01-25 16:25:44.873
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.team.core_3.6.100.v20120524-0627.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-01-25 16:25:44.874
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.team.ui_3.6.201.v20130125-135424.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-01-25 16:25:44.875
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.ui.cheatsheets_3.4.200.v20120521-2344.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-01-25 16:25:44.879
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.ui.intro_3.4.200.v20120521-2344.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-01-25 16:25:45.527
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.monitor (5).
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The activator com.android.ide.eclipse.monitor.MonitorPlugin for bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.monitor is invalid
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1212)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/prefs/AndroidLocation$AndroidLocationException : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClassHoldingLock(ClasspathManager.java:632)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:607)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:492)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.monitor.MonitorPlugin.<clinit>(MonitorPlugin.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:167)
    ... 33 more
```

I have looked at similar problems and tried a few solutions like:

- open Android Studio **Run As Administrator**
- run either of two files `monitor.exe` or `monitor.bat` in Sdk\tools **Run As Administrator**
- change the Gradle version to lower versions (although I am not sure the versions I changed to the right version - if this is the issue: different versions conflict, please tell me which part I need to change)

but it still doesn't work... 
Hope anyone know the answer and thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you check if the path to monitor.exe doesn't contain any spaces ?

Comment: @ArthurAttout this might be a silly question.. but how can I check the path to monitor.exe?

Comment: Should be under "Android\sdk\tools\lib\monitor-x86_64\monitor.exe"